# Seeking code behind Fix Geometries tool in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, gdal, geometry, c++, invalid-data

I used the "Fix Geometries" tool in the Processing Toolbox of QGIS 3.6 to repair a vector layer that was giving me trouble. The tool in QGIS worked just fine, but I was hoping to find out the actual algorithm or Python/C++ code used to implement this feature. I was wondering if anyone knew what code was used to actually implement this tool and fix geometries. Or if there is a different an better way to fix the geometries, any such recommendation would work too.

So let me explain a little bit. I did look up the [QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=fix%20geometries#fix-geometries) for the "Fix Geometries" tool in the Processing Toolbox. Unfortunately, that documentation does not explain how it fixes the geometry - meaning the algorithm. Here is a little excerpt from the documentation:

> Fix geometries
>
> Attempts to create a valid representation of a given
> invalid geometry without losing any of the input vertices. Already
> valid geometries are returned without further intervention. Always
> outputs multi-geometry layer.

I also looked in the Log window of the Fix Geometries tool, but it did not seem to show the GDAL code or such, as in other tools.

In the past I have resolved this issue by wrapping a narrow buffer around the geometry of interest, to overcome invalid geometry errors. Of course this does create some errors in the resulting layers. However, I saw that the Fix Geometry tool did not seem to add a buffer, and hence seemed to solve the invalid geometry problem without introducing some error. Hence I was wondering if anyone knew the code behind that tool.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code is in GitHub. The Fix Geometries tool is a wrapper to the function `LWGEOM_GEOS_makeValid`, which then calls different functions for different geometry types. You can read the various `LWGEOM_GEOS_makeValid*` functions such as the polygon one in the file [qgsgeometrymakevalid.cpp](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/core/geometry/qgsgeometrymakevalid.cpp#L475)